# Git versioning conventions

Tags: git, versioning

I have a project that I track with Git.  For the most part I have had no problem with the Git paradigm, but there is one issue that I haven't quite figured out.  Currently, my `master` branch points to code that will be released at some point.  Topic branches are merged into `master` when they're ready, and into `develop` to test that they work with other dev code.  (By the way, I tried Git Flow and didn't like it.)

The problem with this scheme is that builds from `master` or `develop` appear to have the same version as the last stable release, because I incremented the version right before tagging a release.  I don't want this--I want unstable code to refer to itself as such!  My question:  **What are popular and/or usable conventions for committing version bumps?**  Also, what branching and tagging models could be used to avoid this type of situation?  I'd love something simple, because my project isn't large enough to warrant a big Linux kernel-style model :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at how it is done in Linux kernel by [scripts/setlocalversion](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=scripts/setlocalversion).

Basically, this script tries to guess version from closest tagged commit. If current commit is tagged, this tag is taken as clean version.
If not, it appends current commit short sha to tag to become a version.
If current tree has any uncommitted changes, it may append string "dirty" on top of that.

Note that this is somewhat simplified explanation (in reality it also looks for version numbers in main `Makefile`).

Some other tools also adopted similar versioning approach, notably [u-boot](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=tools/setlocalversion).

Comment: Splendid, splendid!  One question:  Is this a git hook?  Or is it run at build time?

Comment: I believe this is build time

Comment: Hmmm.  Then what does the raw git tree use as its version?

Comment: I think it will default to versions from main `Makefile` if nothing can be found - read the script, it is not that complicated

Comment: Thanks.  I read the script and understand basically what it does.  I have one last question:  How do you recommend I handle creating a tarball using `git archive`?  There would be no .git directory then, and therefore nothing for the script to ask about the version.

Comment: You can create some untracked file by your make release script, like VERSION or something, which will contain version of this release. But I think this file should be completely ignored if git is functional. Note that Linux kernel is using version from tracked Makefile in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Semantic Versioning is popular - http://semver.org/

Comment: Whoops, I guess my question did solicit that type of response.  I've seen Semantic Versioning and like it.  However, I want to know how to manage Git commits so that development code refers to itself as such (in version numbers).  I've updated my question.